# Flutter news feed implementation

Tags: flutter

I’ve been working with flutter for a while now. There’s this blogging app I’ve been working on I use firebase to save and retrieve the data. But I just want to know if there’s any other method of implementing a news feed in flutter.

Comment: what do you mean by other method? another online service ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Ok. What I’m saying is is there a way to implement post feeds like Facebook, instagram without using firebase??